# Can't display files after editing Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, ftp

I am new to server stuff. I have a little problem with my ftp. I have connected my netbeans to my server via FTP. However, everytime i change the code, this will appear on my site

Message: include(/var/www/html/application/controllers/api.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied

I am temporarily using chmod 777 just to show the files everytime I update.

Comment: Whatever your problem is, **`chmod 777` is wrong and dangerous.** You should revert to somewhat more sane permissions (perhaps `chmod 755`?) and check that the file still contains what you want it to contain.

Comment: @tripleee 
 
I tried the command ls-l , it shows this before edit -rwx rwx rwx ; after edit : -rw-----------

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to fix your problem, just pointing out that your attempted workaround has serious problems, potentially fatal if the destination is a shared computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Preserve Remote File Permissions` under `Run Configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `ls -l` and check that the user is correct. Refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership) if you need to change it.

Comment: I tried the command, it shows this:
before edit -rwx rwx rwx, after edit : -rw-----------